# Cartesian product not working with String list

Tags: python, list, loops, optimization, python-itertools

I'm trying to get from:
`list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`

to:

```
combinations = [['a','b'], ['a','c'], ['a','d'],
                ['b','c'], ['b','d'],
                ['c','d']]
```

*(formatting just for readability in stackoverflow)*

So, the cartesian product, all combinations, distinct regardless of order, and no `['a','a']` responses.

I've tried using zip ( `tuple(zip(list*4))` ) and itertools (both permutations and product `list(itertools.product(list, list))`) but am struggling to clean it up. Itertools kind of works but I'm struggling to remove the dupes.

Is there a cleaner way? If not, please can someone help me out with the itertools response

Comment: `itertools.combinations(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], r=2)`

Comment: The reason that a cartesian product isn't working for you, is that **the result you want is not a cartesian product**. This is a rare case, really. People **constantly** ask about "combinations" when they actually **do** want a Cartesian product; I can't remember the last time I saw the opposite.

Comment: Well now I do feel special. Thanks azro & Karl !